# Multiple roundtrips vs cross joins

Tags: sql-server, join, entity-framework

I have a feeling the answer is "it depends on...", but I'm wondering if there's a concrete answer.

In Entity Framework, you build a query using C# code, and the framework converts to SQL and sends to the server to pull down the data. Suppose I want to retrieve a record from three tables. I've got at least three choices:

1. Use straight SQL (manual ADO.NET), send three `SELECT` statements in the same command, and map the results one resultset at a time with a DataReader. This is clearly the best approach from the database perspective, but it's the most work since I wouldn't be able to use the Entity Framework approach.
2. Send three separate commands from Entity Framework - this requires three roundtrips to the database server:

```
Person person1 = context.Persons.First(p => p.PersonID == 1);
Car car1 = context.Cars.First(c => c.CarID == 1);
House house1 = context.Houses.First(h => h.HouseID == 1);
// translates to the following SQL, one roundtrip at a time:
SELECT TOP(1) [p].[PersonID], [p].[PersonName] FROM [Person] AS [p] WHERE [p].[PersonID] = 1
SELECT TOP(1) [c].[CarID], [c].[CarName] FROM [Car] AS [c] WHERE [c].[CarID] = 1
SELECT TOP(1) [h].[HouseID], [h].[HouseName] FROM [House] AS [h] WHERE [h].[HouseID] = 1
```

3. Make one big ugly statement which still uses Entity Framework with a single command and a single statement:

```
var query = (from p in context.Persons.Where(p => p.PersonID == 1)
             from c in context.Cars.Where(c => c.CarID == 1)
             from h in context.Houses.Where(h => h.HouseID == 1)
             select new { p, c, h }).First();
Person person2 = query.p;
Car car2 = query.c;
House house2 = query.h;
// which makes the following SQL:
SELECT TOP(1) [p].[PersonID], [p].[PersonName], [t].[CarID], [t].[CarName], [t0].[HouseID], [t0].[HouseName]
FROM [Person] AS [p]
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT [c].[CarID], [c].[CarName] FROM [Car] AS [c] WHERE [c].[CarID] = 1
) AS [t]
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT [h].[HouseID], [h].[HouseName] FROM [House] AS [h] WHERE [h].[HouseID] = 1
) AS [t0]
WHERE [p].[PersonID] = 1
```

The cross joins end up just flattening out the result since there's only one record returned per table, and the right indexes fire, so I would think the database would be happy with it - fewer roundtrips but the same amount of data returned.

The code in #3 is uglier, but that's not what I'm asking - I'm just asking from a performance perspective. Do the cross joins in the third example cause any potential issues? Maybe locking problems or extra CPU or memory that wouldn't otherwise be needed by using individual commands?

Comment: This will definitely *depend*, and it depends more specifically on your schema, indexes, and data sizes. If you want to really dig in on this, add the query plans (https://pastetheplan.com) for all three versions along with the full schema & index DDL. You could also `UNION` the results together which may be less messy than CROSS APPLY (to me, at least).

Comment: Josh's answer is great, but I wanted to point out that this is premature optimization because it does so very much depend.  Use entity framework and then monitor performance to identify queries that go sideways.  You/the DBA can then recommend indexes or if it needs more specific hand-holding change to a stored procedure.  Our company lets the developers use EF as they wish, but when the data team identifies a performance issue we focus TLC on the area.  sometimes tweaks to EF, sometimes data stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's worth mentioning up front that those two queries might not return the same results.  Three separate queries by ID will always return your three rows.  In the `CROSS JOIN` approach, if `PersonID = 1` doesn't exist, the information about the other two entities won't be returned.  So your application has to be certain that all of these IDs exist, or you might get unexpected results.

---

As long as your tables each have a unique clustered index (or primary key) on the ID column (or a covering nonclustered index - the point is a seek to the correct row is possible), the performance difference between the two approaches, from a SQL Server perspective, is negligible.

Both approaches will result in 3 seeks against the clustered index.  Neither should go parallel, or require sorting, and the cross join should use nested loops - so no memory grants would be needed in either case.

The three batches approach is pretty obvious:

[image: Screenshot of SSMS execution plan showing 3 seeks in 3 batches]

The `CROSS JOIN` approach looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of SSMS execution plan show 3 seeks in two cross joins]

The way this plan operates, each seek operator executes, at most, once:

- The seek on `PK_House` returns one row to the Nested Loops operator
- This triggers execution of the seek on `PK_Person`, which returns one row to the same Nested Loops operator
- This "flattened" row is passed to the next Nested Loops operator...
- ...which triggers execution of the seek on `PK_Car`, returning one row to that second Nested Loops operator
- This single flattened row is returned to the top operator, which satisfies its request for one row, so no more rows are requested

---

If you want to not write cross joins all over your app (potentially confusing to other developers), you can avoid the overhead of multiple roundtrips by using one of the Entity Framework extensions that provides "future" queries.  These let you queue up multiple queries, and they will all be sent and resolved in one batch when the result of any of them is needed.

One such extension is [Entity Framework Plus - `query-future`](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-future).

Comment: Thank you for detailing that out - makes sense. And that query-future thing looks amazing, looks like it is for exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @JoeEnos Awesome, glad I could help!  Yeah, I've used `Future` queries with NHibernate for years, and have always been surprised that EF didn't have it natively.